# php session - destruir todas as sessions e manter apenas uma ativa

Tags: php, session

Olá,

Preciso destruir todas as sessions ao realizar logout de um sistema, com exceção de apenas uma... alguém saberia como implementar isso com php?

Por exemplo:

- Digamos q eu tenha 5 sessions ativas quando o usuário está logado:

  ```
  $session1 = $_SESSION['session1'];
  $session2 = $_SESSION['session2'];
  $session3 = $_SESSION['session3'];
  $session4 = $_SESSION['session4'];
  $session5 = $_SESSION['session5'];
  ```
- Quando realizar o logout, quero destruir 4 destas sessions, porém tem uma que preciso manter ativa... como ficaria nessa parte? tentei assim:

  ```
  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['session4'])){

        session_destroy(); 

  }//end if
  ```

  - assim não deu certo... como seria o correto?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81607/discussion-on-question-by-neo-php-session-destruir-todas-as-sessions-e-manter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta a perceber mal $_SESSION representa a sessão atual, é um array associativo com os dados da sessão, $_SESSION['session1'] representa variável guardada nessa sessão.

para eliminar uma variável da sessão pode fazer

```
unset($_SESSION['session1']);
```

para eliminar todas variáveis

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

para eliminar todas as variáveis excepto a variável com a chave 'session1'

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {

    if ($key != 'session1') {

        unset($_SESSION[$key]);

    }
}
```

Comment: compreendo como destruir todas e como destruir uma por uma. A questão é, imagina que tenhamos 20sessions... 19precisam ser destruídas e apenas uma precisa ser mantida.. quero uma solução onde o código trabalhe a favor de destruir todas e fazer um if para que somente uma fique ativa, sem a necessidade de fazer unset para cada uma...

Comment: Veja a atualização da resposta

Comment: me pareceu estar correto, mas estava aqui testando e não deu certo... coloquei no php sand box para poder compartilhar: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cabb41dce09f6e360af8cb2885e02b9cb0f6fbf8

Comment: Em PHP quando você executa  $session1 = $_SESSION['session1'];  está a guardar um cópia do valor e portanto qualquer alteração  $_SESSION['session1'] não vai afectar $session1 elas não apontam para o mesmo valor mas não são a mesma variável'

Comment: No caso o exemplo está correcto se executar  print_r($_SESSION); após o for vai verificar que as outras variáveis foram removidas de sessão ($_SESSION)

Comment: Realizei mais um teste aguardando o tempo de resposta do servidor. Com esse exemplo ficou resolvido. Perfeito @Jorge Costa

Answer (score 7):

Você  poderia criar uma variável temporariamente para receber o valor da variável da sessão, destruir todas e depois criar apenas apenas a variável da sessão que desejar.

```
$auxiliar = $_SESSION['session4'];

session_unset();

$_SESSION['session4'] = $auxiliar;
```

Outra forma, mais direta, de fazer isso:

```
$_SESSION = ['session4' => $_SESSION['session4']]
```

Comment: Vou testar, mas ali onde colocou sesison_unset(), seria o session_destroy() para que todas fossem destruidas, não? E quando isso ocorrer, a session temporaria não será destruída junto?

Comment: `session_destroy()` irá destruir a `$_SESSION` criada. `sesison_unset()` irá destruir as variáveis de `$_SESSION` é como se você estivesse fazendo `unset($_SESSION["varname"])`

Answer (score 0):

Você dando **session_destroy();** você vai destruir todas as session, 
para você destruir apenas as especificas use **unset();**

sendo assim:

```
unset($_SESSION['session1'], $_SESSION['session2']);
```

**RESULTADO:** você destruirá as 2 session (ou as que você colocar dentro do **unset();** ).

Comment: "destruir todas, exceto uma" significa que ele não quer especificar quais ele quer excluir, mas sim especificar qual ele quer manter - oposto do que colocou na resposta.

Comment: @Ewerson S. compreendo como destruir todas e como destruir uma por uma. A questão é, imagina que tenhamos 20sessions... 19precisam ser destruídas e apenas uma precisa ser mantida.. quero uma solução onde o código trabalhe a favor de destruir todas e fazer um if para que somente uma fique ativa, sem a necessidade de fazer unset para cada uma...